# Restricting access to Index with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, cancan

I'm using cancan to lock down an app that I've created.  It's working great but I can't quite figure out how to lock down the index of a particular model in the way I want.

The index looks like this:

```
    def index
        @incorporations = current_user.incorporations("created_at DESC")
    end
```

What I'm after is really simple: want the index to only be accessed by registered users.  I've been using an `if user_signed_in` statement but I was wondering if there's a way I should be using cancan to do this for the sake of consistency.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer turned out to be quite simple, which I got from [here.](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/209)

All I needed to do was add the following to my `ablility.rb`:

```
can :index, Incorporation
```

And then add the following to the controller in question:

```
authorize! :index, Ability
```

That's it!